# How to check selected time passed from current time?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check here my selectedTime is passed or not from current time.

```
DateTime selectedTime = DateTime.parse('2023-12-29 13:08:04Z');

final currentTime = DateTime.now();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check by using the below methods:

```
DateTime selectedTime = DateTime.parse('2023-12-29 13:08:04Z');

final currentTime = DateTime.now();

currentTime.isBefore(selectedTime); // Output => false

currentTime.isAfter(selectedTime); // Output => true
```